# Input Mismatch exception Java

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I am getting the input mismatch exception error on my code.
I am getting error at the Engine displacement line.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Car[] arr;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of car details to created");
        int number=scanner.nextInt();
        arr=new Car[number];
        for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        {
             System.out.println("Enter Car Id");
             String carId=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Model Number");
             String modelNumber=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Colour");
             String colour=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Transmission Type");
             String transmissionType=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Fuel Type");
             String fuelType=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Engine Type");
             String engineType=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Body Type");
             String bodyType=scanner.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter Engine Displacement");
              //Here Input.mismatchexception
             int engineDisplacement=scanner.nextInt();
             System.out.println("Enter Boot Space");
             int bootSpace=scanner.nextInt();
             System.out.println("Enter Seat Capacity");
             int seatCapacity=scanner.nextInt(); 
             arr[i]=new Car(carId,modelNumber,colour,transmissionType,fuelType,engineType,bodyType,engineDisplacement,bootSpace,seatCapacity);
        }
```

Input-
1
TN-7474
A4
Black
Automatic
Petrol
2.0LTFSI
Sedan
1998
460
5

Comment: `int engineDisplacement=scanner.nextInt()` reads "Sedan", not "1998"

Comment: Yess but how do i resolve this? I have already taken the input of bodytype so why it is reading sedan?